# Blueimp jQuery File Upload Integrated with Asp.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use jquery blueimp multiple file upload with Asp.Net. 
After two days of unsuccessful attempts, I decided to ask maybe someone will share the working example.

I would be very grateful.

Comment: I cant make progress bar work at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the exact demo files, without having to use that .NET example linked in a prior comment.  Change the form action link to point to a handler.ashx file that you create.

So, in the form on index.html, add the url to the handler you created as the action:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="GongosHandler.ashx" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then do a basic handler coded as the following:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";//"application/json";
    var r = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ViewDataUploadFilesResult>();


    for (var x = 0; x < context.Request.Files.Count; x++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile hpf = context.Request.Files[x] as HttpPostedFile;
        string FileName = string.Empty;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE")
        {
            string[] files = hpf.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
            FileName = files[files.Length - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            FileName = hpf.FileName;
        }
        if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
            continue;
        string savedFileName = context.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + FileName);
        try
        {
            hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }


        r.Add(new ViewDataUploadFilesResult()
        {
            thumbnailUrl = savedFileName,
            name = FileName,
            length = hpf.ContentLength,
            type = hpf.ContentType,
            url =  string.Format("/Uploads/{0}", FileName),
            deleteUrl =  string.Format("/Uploads/{0}", FileName) 
        });
        var uploadedFiles = new
        {
            files = r.ToArray()
        };

        //was returning a new json string everytime, so then duplicating if 
        //sending multiple files. Example, file 1 was in first position,
        //then file 1 & 2 in second position, and so on. So, I only grab,
        //the last JSON instance to get all files.
        if (x  == (context.Request.Files.Count - 1))
        {
            var jsonObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(uploadedFiles, Formatting.Indented);
            string jsonHttpOutputStream = jsonObj.ToString();

            context.Response.Write(jsonHttpOutputStream);
        }
    }

}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ViewDataUploadFilesResult
{
    public string thumbnailUrl { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string deleteUrl { get; set; }
}
```

And at a basic level, that will render and work. Then, you have to just tweak some of the code here and there, to get it functioning how you want. This handler though, is all you need to process the upload correctly.  Good luck!

Comment: can anybody provide a sample on this

Comment: i tried this, doesnt work for me. if i run the thing separately and have a handler run from vs i get the error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <, if i run the whole thing in vs (including all the html files etc) i get the error: Method Not Allowed

Comment: Here is a good MVC5 sample:  https://github.com/CodeHeight/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC5